# How to not stop RedHawk processing even if there is no request from RedHawk-IDE

Tags: redhawksdr

I use Red Hawk v2.1.0 to realize the AM demodulation part with three components.

```
Platform            --> Xilinx Zynq 7035 (ARM Coretex A9*2) 
Oparating System(OS)--> embedded Linux.
```

When connecting the **RedHawk-IDE** on the external PC with the Ether and displaying the waveform between the components, an abnormal sound is occured.
At this time, when I disconnect the LAN cable, the AM demodulation processing of Red Hawk inside the ARM will cease.
RedHawk inside the ARM appears to be waiting for requests from RedHawk-IDE on the external PC.
From this, it seems that abnormal noise will occur when requests from RedHawk-IDE on the external PC are delayed.
How can I keep RedHawk's AM demodulation processing inside the ARM running without stopping while connecting the RedHawk-IDE of the external PC and monitoring the waveform?
Environment is below. 
CPU：Xilinx Zynq ARM CoretexA9 2cores 600MHz 
OS：Embedded Linux Kernel 3.14 RealTimePatch 
FrameLength：5.333ms（48kHz sampling, 256 data)

Answer (score 0):

I have seen similar, if not identical issues, when running on an ARM board. Tracking down the exact issue may be difficult and in my experience hasn't been redhawk specific and has really been an issue with omniORB or its configuration. I believe one of the fixes for me was recompiling omniORB rather than using the omniORB package provided by my OS. (Which didn't make any sense to me at the time as I used the same flags & build process as the package maintainer)

First I would confirm this issue is specific to ARM. If it's easy enough to setup the same components, waveforms etc. on a 2nd x86_64 host and validate the problem does not occur.

Second I would try a "quick fix" of setting the omniORB timeouts on the arm host using the `/etc/omniORB.cfg` file and setting:

```
clientCallTimeOutPeriod = 2000
clientConnectTimeOutPeriod = 2000
```

This will set a 2 second timeout on CORBA interactions for both the connect portion and the call completion portion. In the past this has served as a quick fix for me but does not address the underlying issue. If this "fixes" it for you then you've at least narrowed part of the issue down and you could enable omniORB debugging using the traceLevel configuration option to find what call is timing out. See [this sample configuration file for all options](https://github.com/snaewe/omniorb/blob/4_1/omniORB/sample.cfg)

If you want to dive into the underlying issues you'd need to see what the IDE and framework are doing when things lock up. With the IDE this is easy; simply find the PID of the java process and run `kill -3 <pid>` and a full stack trace will be printed in the terminal that is running the IDE. This can give you hints as to what calls are locked up.  For the framework you'll need to use GDB and connect to the process in question and tell GDB to print the stack trace. You'd have to do some investigation ahead of time to determine which process is locking up.

If it ends up being an issue with the Java CORBA implementation on x86_64 talking with the C++ CORBA implementation on ARM you could also try launching / configuring / interacting with the ARM board via the REDHAWK python API from your x86_64 host. This may have better compatibility since they both use the same omniORB CORBA implementation.

Comment: I try to change omniORG.cfg, and restart omniNames and omniEvents. Our Radio Frame is 5.33 ms, so I set the elements are below.
clientCallTimeOutPeriod = 2
clientConnectTimeOutPeriod = 2
Because of Modem Processing has finished inside Radio Frame.
However Device Manager will not start. There seems to be no communication between DomainManager and DeviceManager.

Comment: Setting the call timeouts to 2ms is too small.  Try 2000 as recommended and see if that helps

Comment: I try to change the value 2000(2sec). However, there is no change when setting value 0(no timeout). I still get strange sounds. When I check the process movement with Ftrace, it is waiting for a request from the IDE.
The Ether interrupt from the IDE stays for about 5 frames, and it does not perform modem processing for 5.33 ms * 5 = 26.6 ms. Is it setting on IDE side?